# Combinatorics - placing numbered balls (distinguishable) into distinguishable bins

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have 10 balls, numbered $1$ through $10$, and $30$ distinguishable bins. How many ways are there to distribute the balls among the bins?

I think the answer is just $30^{10}$ for this. Is that correct? If not, what am I missing here?

Comment: Assuming you can put as many balls as you want into a bin, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything: your conclusion is correct, barring any restrictions on how the balls are to be distributed: there are indeed $30^{10}$ ways of distributing the numbered balls.

Comment: excellent, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!